# How to break line into tcpdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

i have a problem with tcpdf break line.
In perfexcrm when you make an invoice automatically create a pdf like code below

```
foreach ($pdf_custom_fields as $field) {
$value = get_custom_field_value($invoice->id, $field['id'], 'invoice');
if ($value == '') {
    continue;
}
$invoice_info .= $field['name'] . ': ' . $value . '<br />';
```

But when print pdf the file looks bad.

How to break line on this portion of code?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct only. Make sure $value is string.